# Extremely slow MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate

Tags: iphone, email, cocos2d-iphone

I have a bit of a strange problem.  I am trying to send in-app email.  I am also using Cocos2d.  It works, so far as I get the mail window and I can send mail, but it is extremely slow.  It seems to only accept touches every second or so.  I checked the cpu usage, and it is quite low.  I paused my director, so nothing else should be happening.  Any ideas?  I am pulling my hair out.

I looked at some examples and did the following:

Made my scene the mail delegate:

```
@interface MyLayer : CCLayer <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> {
    ...
}
```

And implemented the following function in the scenes:

```
-(void) showEmailWindow: (id) sender {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];

    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject: @"My subject here"];

    NSString *emailBody = @"<h1>Here is my email!</h1>";

    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

    [myMail presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];
    [picker release];

}
```

I also implemented the mailComposeController, to handle the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over at the cocos2d forum (http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum), CJ helped me out.

The important part was that I wasn't calling `[dicector stopAnimation]`, but there were some other good bits, too.

I now do this before I `presentModalViewController`:

```
CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
[director pause];
[director stopAnimation];
[director.openGLView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

And then when I get the callback, in `mailComposeController`, I do this at the end:

```
CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
[director.openGLView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[director startAnimation];
[director resume];

[myMail.view.superview removeFromSuperview];
```

Hope this helps someone else.